# PDFBox - How to push/unpush a PD(Push)Button

Tags: java, pdfbox

For building a workaround, I'd like to know if it's possible to push/unpush a `PD(Push)Button` with pdfbox 2.0.12 or later.

```
PDButton pdButton = (PDButton) field;
pdButton.setValue("pushed");
```

Is there a certain value that can be used to push/unpush the button?

I'm aware that this should rather be solved with a `PDCheckBox`, but as most of our PDF-templates use buttons rather than checkboxes to display checkboxes I'd like to ease the migration of those files.

---

**Update 1**

As suggested in the comments I tried setting the button to one, but that leads to an `IllegalStateException`.

Code

```
PDButton btn = (PDButton) field;
btn.setValue("1");
```

Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceEntry.getSubDictionary(PDAppearanceEntry.java:97)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDButton.getOnValueForWidget(PDButton.java:348)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDButton.getOnValues(PDButton.java:319)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDButton.checkValue(PDButton.java:370)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDButton.setValue(PDButton.java:157)
```

**Update 2**

Not possible. Only checkboxes can be checked/unchecked. We'll fix our PDF templates.

Comment: "A pushbutton field shall have a field type of Btn and the Pushbutton flag (see Table 226) set to one. Because this type of button retains no permanent value, it shall not use the V and DV entries in the field dictionary"

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks for the quick response! I updated the question based on your feedback and it produces an exception. Did I use the correct value? Also I don't understand which table you're referring to.

Comment: That was from the PDF specification ( https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf ). The one is for the Pushbutton flag, not the value. What I meant to say is "you can't". If your file allows something like that, then either it isn't a pushbutton, or it is some magic with javascript.

Comment: *"most of our PDF-templates use buttons rather than checkboxes to display checkboxes"* - that sounds extremely weird, in particular considering @Tilman's quote from the specification. So if your templates function at all (i.e. remember a state), they merely do so by chance or by mis-use of sound features...

Comment: I agree that's weird and not as it should be. We ended up just de-rendering the checkbox alltogether and will request proper checkboxes for when a checkbox shall be unchecked.